# RollupJS: hot-reload doesn't refresh the page with ASP.NET server

Tags: typescript, asp.net-web-api, rollupjs, hot-reload

I'm working on a JS library with RollupJS and static files are served by an ASP.NET server. To improve my DX I want to have hot-reload.

On file changed, bundle file is rebuild with changed but no refresh happen. There is no errors in the console

I'm on a monorepo (directories):

- server (ASP.NET)
- library (JS)

rollup.config.js

```
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import terser from '@rollup/plugin-terser';
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy';
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import pkg from './package.publish.json' assert { type: 'json' };
import html from 'rollup-plugin-html';
import css from 'rollup-plugin-import-css';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';

const outputs = [
  {
    file: `./dist/${pkg.exports['.'].import.default}`,
    format: 'esm',
  },
  {
    file: `./dist/${pkg.exports['.'].require.default}`,
    format: 'cjs',
  },
];

const config = [
  {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: [...outputs],
    plugins: [
      typescript(),
      terser(),
      replace({
        preventAssignment: true,
        values: {
          '.css?inline': '.css',
        },
      }),
      html(),
      css(),
      copy({
        targets: [{
          src: './package.publish.json',
          dest: 'dist',
          rename: () => 'package.json',
        }],
      }),
      livereload({
        watch: 'dist',
        verbose: true,
        delay: 600,
      }),
    ],
  },
];
export default config;
```

index.html (run by ASP.NET server)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <script>window.WSPORT = '6969'</script>
  <script type="module" src="library.mjs"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
  <script type="module">
    window.setInterval(() => {
      window.set('dateTime', new Date());
    }, 1000)
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

In `Program.cs` I specified where to import static files

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "..", "..", "library", "dist", "esm")),
        RequestPath = new PathString("")
});
```

Did I miss something in my config ?